# How to call getSupportFragmentManager() from a fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, datetimepicker

I want to use a custom date and time picker in my code for that  i created a seperate package and put all the date and time picker classes there.
The code is running smoothly if i'm running it from main activity but when i want to call from a fragment it's not recognizing **getSupportFragmentManager()** method 
the call which i'm making from my fragment is :

```
SimpleDateTimePicker simpleDateTimePicker = SimpleDateTimePicker.make(
            "Set Date & Time Title",
            new Date(),
            this,
            getSupportFragmentManager()
    );

    simpleDateTimePicker.show();
```

Please help, thank you guys.

Comment: getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() tried this ?

Comment: you can use getFragmentManager() directly in place of getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: yes , but it doesn't work

Comment: tried that too no good luck :( it shows
Error:(106, 43) error: incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Comment: @ManishNegi You need to extend your class from android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity, not just from standard android.Activity to get this method.

Comment: but if i'd do that i think i won't be able to launch fragment

Comment: Did you try using FragmentActivity?

Comment: yes when i used that, i was not able to create fragment object

Comment: Can you post your Main class?

Comment: i can post but the code is huge you might get confused 
the code i posted alongwith question is what i am doing on a click event to use all the classes of custom datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

**You don't**.

You need to call `getChildFragmentManager()` from the Fragment. Attempting to call `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

looks like `SimpleDateTimePicker` class is your own class, which accepts only `android.app.FragmentManager`, not  `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. So you can use that class only with API11 or higher. If you want to use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`, you need to edit your `SimpleDateTimePicker` to accept that `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` in constructor

**EDIT:**

ok, there are 2 different classes: `android.app.FragmentManager` and `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. The second one is a compatibility implementation of the first one. Most apps use the second, as it allowed to be used before API 11. And the class from your link uses the first one. There are two ways to fix it:
1st - you start using `android.app.FragmentManager` instead of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. It will cause app work only above api 11.
2nd way is changing code of `SimpleDateTimePicker` to use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. It is more correct way I think.

Comment: actually i didn't code that class I am just a beginner so i took the code from
[link](http://armanpagilagan.blogspot.in/2014/05/creating-custom-date-and-time-picker-in.html)

Comment: @ManishNegi, then you should take time to understand the code, not just take it "as is" and try to use it.

Comment: Okay but i'm not getting really that stuff, intially i used that with a blank activity in another program and that was working

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your `frgaments` extends from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or `android.app.Fragment` .If it is `android.app.Fragment` then call `getActivity().getFragmentManager();` or if it extends from support `frgament` then call `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();`

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
getBaseActivity().getFragmentManager()
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`getChildFragmentManager()`